# Sphinx: Unable to open Sphinx/mixture_weights

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

Im executing this command:

```
    ./bw \
    -hmmdir Sphinx \
    -moddeffn cmusphinx-en-us-ptm-5.2/mdef \
    -ts2cbfn .ptm. \
    -feat 1s_c_d_dd \
    -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 \
    -cmn current \
    -agc none \
    -dictfn cmudict-en-us.dict \
    -ctlfn arctic20.fileids \
    -lsnfn arctic20.transcription \
    -accumdir .
```

And Im getting this error message:

> ERROR: "s3io.c", line 260: Unable to open Sphinx/mixture_weights for reading: No such file or directory

The "mixture_weights" file is in the same Folder as the mdef file. What am I doing wrong?
THanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify wrong hmmdir. Try this

```
./bw \
    -hmmdir cmusphinx-en-us-ptm-5.2 \
    -moddeffn cmusphinx-en-us-ptm-5.2/mdef \
    -ts2cbfn .ptm. \
    -feat 1s_c_d_dd \
    -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 \
    -cmn current \
    -agc none \
    -dictfn cmudict-en-us.dict \
    -ctlfn arctic20.fileids \
    -lsnfn arctic20.transcription \
    -accumdir .
```